# Como pasar esta funcion a una funcion lambda

Tags: python, lambda

estoy haciendo una funcion para comprobar si in numero es primo y me gustaria saber como pasar esta funcion a una funcion lambda

```
def check_prime_no(num):
if num > 1:
   for i in range(2, num):
       if (num % i) == 0:
           return False
   else:
       return True
```

Muchas gracias

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Los lambda están limitados a un simple expresión. Lo que haremos será usar comprensión de listas para generar una con el resto del valor contra cada potencial divisor.

Si todos son distintos de cero (`True`), entonces es primo. Esto lo chequeamos con la función `all`, que recibe un iterable y devuelve `True` si todos los elementos son `True`(distintos de cero en este caso).

```
lam = lambda num : all([ num % i for i in range(2, num)])
```

#### Demo

```
lam = lambda num : all([ num % i for i in range(2, num)])

for i in range(2, 20):
    primo = lam(i)
    if primo:
        print(i)
```

produce:

```
2
3
5
7
11
13
17
19

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: Optimización simple, haz el `range()` solo hasta `num//2`. Optimización mejor (aunque menos obvia), hazlo hasta `int(num ** .5)`

Comment: Optimización extra, usa comprensión de generador, no comprensión de listas. Es decir, `all(num % i for i in range(2, num))` sin los corchetes. De esa manera se ahorra memoria y velocidad.

Comment: Seria posible realizar la funcion comprobar_primo con el operador reduce() ?